# Why can the InputStream class be instantiated? Isn't it an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, io

I read that the `InputStream` class,which is the superclass for all byte-stream input classes, is an **abstract class** which is inheritted by other specific byte-stream input classes. However, I also read that in *java.lang.System* there is an object that refers to the **standard input stream** which we refer to as `java.lang.System.in` and that object instantiates the class InputStream.

In Sun API documentation, "in" is defined as:

```
public static final InputStream in
```

But i know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It's the difference between the left- and right-hand sides of a declaration and assignment.  You can declare abstract and interface types; that's the static compile time type of a reference.  The right-hand side expresses the dynamic, runtime type of the object on the heap.

Comment: Quick test `System.out.println(System.in.getClass());` and you will know it's actual class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get how it is now. I should have looked into it more. But just asking for a clarification: "Is `java.lang.System.in` set to be a reference to `java.io.BufferedInputStream` by default or can this change?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable "in",here, just holds a reference to an Object that can fullfill the requirement of "is a InputStream". That means that variable "in" can hold any instante of a concrete Class that extends InputStream as for example AudioInputStream, which fulfill the condition "is a InputStream". It's something related to the polymorphism I think